# Handling multiple datatypes in mapping of single field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I ran into an issue, after lot of scratching and going to and fro over lot of things I couldn't determine the solution.
So in my system where I am logging the events from different API's to my Elasticsearch cluster. I am seeing issues where for particular field I am getting two types of values
as in

```
Lets assume we have a field called updated_by
In some events I am getting data as 
{
    "name": "event_1",
    "updated_by": "xyz@gmail.com"
}

for some events I am getting data as

{
    "name": "event_2",
    "updated_by": {
        "email_id": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "user_id" : "user_1"
     }
}
 
Note:- You can segregate based on name field, so event_1 will have the same type of response always and event_2 will the same kind of response always
```

I am indexing them under the same index therefore one of the document always errors out giving mapping mismatch exception.

What I would like to do is find a way by which I can index all the records without loosing any of the record. I am ok with loosing the ability of querying on the field.
Anyone in this community have faced similar challenges

I do have the option of indexing them as separate index based on name field, but this will cause issues of dealing with hundreds of index, which I want to avoid.
As a last option I can think of flattening out the complete json so that can be stored in a same file.

Comment: you can make "updated_by" as dynamic object (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html#dynamic) and keep adding whatever fields you like at runtime.

Comment: @varshneyanmol this would never work for both the case. My second case will go through or succeed but my first case will not because in my first case I am passing a concrete value and in second case passing an object. IMO dynamic works in nested field where we don't know exact number  of field in a nested object.

Comment: But you can make sure that "updated_by" always has an object. If it contains a concrete value(your first case), then you can wrap it up in an object and make it work. For example, you can pass your first case like update_by: {value: "xyz@gmail.com"}

Comment: ok .. i got your thought, nice idea. But my problem is I can't control the source of data. I am free to do anything at elastic end but I can't do anything at source level that's kind of not an option for me. As the same data is being used by multiple systems.